# Airflow: "ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied" using GoogleCloudStorageToS3Operator

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I would like to transfer a file from GCS to S3. The first operator (S3KeySensor) to test my connection works well. But unfortunately, I get an error with the second one (GoogleCloudStorageToS3Operator): 
"An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied" which is an S3 error.

```
# test
sensor = S3KeySensor(
    task_id='check_s3_for_file_in_s3',
    bucket_key='folder1/folder2/*',
    wildcard_match=True,
    bucket_name='test.mydomain.com',
    aws_conn_id='aws_connection',
    timeout=18*60*60,
    poke_interval=120,
    dag=dag)

impressions_from_gcs_to_s3 = GoogleCloudStorageToS3Operator(
    task_id='impressions_from_gcs_to_s3',
    bucket="mygcsbucket",
    delimiter=filename,
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id="google_cloud_storage_default",
    dest_aws_conn_id="aws_connection",
    dest_s3_key="s3://test.mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/",
    dag=dag,
)
```

I am not sure what to do to resolve the issue.

Comment: This is an S3 error. Work with your AWS administrator in getting the user accessing S3 from airflow permission for the ListObjectsV2 operation.

Comment: I have not issue to do:  "aws s3 ls s3://..." Can it be possible without the ListObjectsV2 operation?

Comment: Is your local user that you used to test `aws s3 ls s3://etc` the same as the user for airflow? From your problem, it seems `GoogleCloudStorageToS3Operator` requires the use of `ListObjectsV2` so I would say it is not possible.

Comment: I confirm that it is the exact same user.

Comment: I do not have the list permission at the root of the bucket. Could that be the issue? I can do "aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/folder1/folder2" but not "aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/"

Comment: That sounds like that is the issue!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and you need to add a policy for the execution role of this dag.
I leave you an example in case you need to add or delete objects in the bucket:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-a/*","arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-a",
            .
            .
            .
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-n/*","arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-n"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me is that my AWS user requieres multi factor authentication (MFA) to perform any tasks. For local tests (like just python or Jupyter notebooks) I had to update the MFA daily, but in Airflow you cannot really do that. So, the solution was to create a different user for Airflow with the right permissions and without MFA.